# C# Merge Null Or Not Existing Properties and its properties from strongly typed Model after deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization, merge, reflection, mapping

The problem is I have a config which I can update using my Model, I deploy new update and user won't get updated configuration file, so it will cause null reference exception, etc. Now I just set default values or use new() to make it at least similar to latest configuration value, but its a hell, I need to always support it, what if I'll or someone else even forget to merge null properties?

I have 3 different config files (YAML, XML, JSON),but with single one model.
I want it to merge all null properties, arrays of the arrays, not existing items of the array from default config into existing config, properties of the properties, etc, however I want to save all existing things from the deserialized config.

My Model:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class GuardSettings
{
    public GuardSettings()
    {
    }

    public UnturnedGuardOptions UnturnedGuardOptions { get; set; }
    public UnturnedIntegrityVault UnturnedIntegrityVault { get; set; }
    public LocalTimeOptions LocalTimeOptions { get; set; }
    [YamlIgnore, XmlIgnore] public VanillaOptions VanillaOptions { get; set; }
    public LogReport LogReport { get; set; }
    public DiscordWebhookLaunch DiscordWebhookLaunch { get; set; }
    public DiscordWebhookReject DiscordWebhookReject { get; set; }
    public DiscordWebhookAccept DiscordWebhookAccept { get; set; }
    public DiscordWebhookCancel DiscordWebhookCancel { get; set; }
    public DiscordWebhookReport DiscordWebhookReport { get; set; }
    public DiscordWebhookBans DiscordWebhookBans { get; set; }
    public DiscordWebhookUnbans DiscordWebhookUnbans { get; set; }
    public DatabaseOptions DatabaseOptions { get; set; }
    public UnturnedPanelIntegration UnturnedPanelIntegration { get; set; }
    public BanOptions BanOptions { get; set; }
    public PlayerWhitelist PlayerWhitelist { get; set; }
    public HWIDHistory HWIDHistory { get; set; }
    [YamlMember(Alias = "tpsOptions")] public TPSOptions TPSOptions { get; set; }
    public FeaturesOptions FeaturesOptions { get; set; }
    public Feature[] Features { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Feature
{
    public Feature()
    {
    }

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public Argument[] Arguments { get; set; } = Array.Empty<Argument>();
}

[Serializable]
public class Argument
{
    public Argument()
    {
    }

    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public object? Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I see it, I have default settings just using my custom factory that configures default config with all properties (in a proper way), and the existing settings is a deserialized config from file (YAML, XML or JSON).

```cs
private static GuardSettings Merge(GuardSettings defaultSettings, GuardSettings existingSettings)
```

After that I want to serialize the Merged config to let configuration being updated, so user can change newest properties and be up to date with changes in the config!

I tried to use Reflection and AutoMapper, but with no success.

Comment: I'm unclear what exactly you're asking to be honest. What do you mean by "merge null properties"? Are you saying to want to populate `null` properties in one configuration file with default values from another configuration file?

Comment: @WBuck I'm saying about everything, since it a model I have all public properties (get set), so I want to replace the null or not existing properties from an existing configuration, and do the same with all child (or in simple words, I mean all nested) properties/arrays/classes, etc

Answer (score 0):

The approach I typically use is to initialize optional properties:

```
public class MyConfiguration{
    [JsonRequiredAttribute]
    public string MyRequiredProperty {get;set;} // Required property, no default value needed.
    public long MyOptionalProperty {get;set;} = 42; // Optional property, default value needed
}
```

Many serialization libraries will replace `MyOptionalProperty` from the file if it exist, and leave the default value if it does not. But check that your particular libraries work in this way. There are usually some type of attributes to mark properties as required or not, so you can fairly quickly check that all optional properties has default values.

If there are larger changes to the layout of the configuration it can be useful to create a new type, so you can deserialize the old type and convert it to the new layout by hand. This can be easier if you use "DTOs", i.e. types *only* use for serialization.

Deserializing the object, and then merge it with a default object seem problematic. You would need a fair bit of complicated reflection, and you would have no way to handle value types, i.e. you have no idea if a zero represents a missing value, or just a value set to zero.